# Create a percentage with three numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm trying to write a small script that will convert three numbers into three percentages. Jquery can set the width of three coloured divs to reflect the 'spread' of these numbers.

Think of it as a three part loading bar.

I made some pasta for a two part loading bar, but I have no idea how to add a third percentage. Somebody good at math would be able to turn three numbers into three percentages out of 100.

http://jsfiddle.net/gzz46/1/

```
 var xwidth = (+x/(+x+y)*100);
 var ywidth = (+100-xwidth);
 //var zwidth = (+100-ywidth);
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to add 3 numbers together (which would equal 100%) then find the percentage of each number?  In your jsfiddle example, your numbers are 10, 15, 20.  Add them all = 45, divide each from 45, 10/45 = .222 (or 22.22%), 15/45 = .333 (or 33.33%), 20/45 = .444 (or 44.44%)

Comment: You can't just turn a number into a percentage.  You need a number and a total value or maximum value.  Then just use firstNumber/maximumNumber*100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add them all = 45, divide each from 45, 10/45 = .222 (or 22.22%), 15/45 = .333 (or 33.33%), 20/45 = .444 (or 44.44%)

If you are trying to do what my comment says, change your code to this:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 15;
var z = 20;

var total = x+y+z;

var xwidth = (x/total)*100;
var ywidth = (y/total)*100;
var zwidth = (z/total)*100;

$(".x").css('width', xwidth+'%');
$(".y").css('width', ywidth+'%');
$(".z").css('width', zwidth+'%');
```

or, even cleaner:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 15;
var z = 20;
var total = x+y+z;

$(".x").css('width', (x/total)*100+'%');
$(".y").css('width', (y/total)*100+'%');
$(".z").css('width', (z/total)*100+'%');
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Thanks ntgCleaner for the quick, clean, and concise answer!